# How can I get a feat at level 1 in D&D 5e?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, magic

I was wondering about the magic initiate feat. Because I want to know if you can take it first level because I'm making a human warlock who's always been in-tune with magic even before making the pact and think the feat would work great for the character if I can use it right away.

Answer (score 16):

The only way, RAW, to get a feat at first level, is to be a Variant Human.  PHB page 31, "Variant Human Traits"

If your DM is open to houserules, however, they could simply give all characters a feat if they choose.

Answer (score -3):

Short answer: that's entirely up to your DM.

Expended explanation: Level 1 characters don't stay level 1 for long enough for this to  really matter.  Your party of 4 kills off a few orcs and you're level 2.  That said, one of the notions behind 5e is balance, not dominance.  I suppose that if you could convince your DM why this is important to your character, with justification in your background, sure.  If I were your DM, I would not allow it otherwise.

Comment: downvoted because while it's always up to your DM, it is specifically called out in the PHB and has balancing adjustments associated with it.   your answer is all opinion (btw, the feat would be useful not just at level 1, but 2, 3 the rest of the life of the character since at 4 you could have -two- feats....or a feat and +2)